# Web apps: Separate SQL completely from the code

Tags: php, sql, architecture

This is a design question, I've been thinking about this for a while.

I would like to separate the SQL queries inside independent files or memory locations (for faster access).

The queries will be stored like this:

```
SELECT .... WHERE col = ?
```

When the query is needed, it is fetched from it's location.

A (less maintainable) example alternative would be:

```
$sql = "select ..... where col=". prevent_injection($val) ." and ....";
```

Benefits:

- total separation of the queries: the web developers and the DBAs can work specifically to their role
- cleaner queries

Disadvantages:

- requires a bit of coordination on what each ? means, which is necessary anyway in a big team
- sourcing the SQL at runtime may slow things down a bit, but caching can be used

Any feedback on this approach?

Comment: Big organisations with large SQL systems code everything into stored procedures that provide the total interface to the database. No access for any purpose is permitted outside that system.

Comment: Isn't querying to this procedure the same

Comment: Isn't this what ORMs like EF and ActiveRecord do? i.e. they abstract away the SQL. Also how would this scale once you go beyond a single select statement i.e. CTEs, joins and subselects. I suspect you're then reliant on the RDBMS query analysers. DBAs and SQL devs do have their distinct roles, the DBAs are there to optimise the database infrastructure against your application be it adding faster disks, fs or more CPUs. SQL devs are expected to understand best practice for indexing, schema design and security.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the MVC (Model View Controller) architectural pattern. It will allow you to achieve your goal: Separation of data, logic and presentation.

In MVC, your models will handle all SQL related logic, so that the other two layers will never have to deal with queries.

Have a look at PHP Frameworks which implement the MVC pattern, they will greatly simplify applying this pattern to your project. My personal favourite is [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com), but there are lots of others, such as [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com), [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) et al.

Most of these frameworks also have caching mechanisms as a bonus and they are able to utilize other means of speeding up your web application: Redis and Memcache, for example.

Comment: Also [Presentation-abstraction-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation%E2%80%93abstraction%E2%80%93control) (PAC).

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use two ways for preventing SQL injection.

ORMs like propel, it handle all the SQL injection issue in itself. You don't need to care the details. And several MVC frameworks are using ORMs.

The PHP Data Objects (aka: PDO) extension. You could write your code like below. it also handle all the SQL injection issue in itself

```
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
    $stmt->execute();
```

According to benefits you want, I suggest you can use PDO for clear SQL and keep it light-weight.